# AppSettings.json not using custom TypeConverter for IpAddress

Tags: c#, asp.net, appsettings

I have some IP addresses in my appsettings.json that are properties of type `IPAddress` in a type corresponding to that section. I stumbled upon this question: [ASP Core type converter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57460367/asp-core-type-converter) and implemented the TypeConverter as shown. However, the IP addresses are set to the default value of that type instead of the addresses I have defined. My custom TypeConverter is never called (I copied it exactly from the linked question).

In `Program.Main()` I now have:

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(IPAddress), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(IpAddressConverter)));
        
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        
builder.Services.AddSingleton<Configuration>(_ => configurationRoot.GetSection(nameof(Configuration)).Get<Configuration>());
```

`Configuration.cs`:

```
public class Configuration {
   public IpAddressConfig IpAddressConfig { get; set; }
}
```

`IpAddressConfig.cs`:

```
public class IpAddressConfig {
   public IPAddress HostAddress { get; set; }
   public IPAddress Remote1Address { get; set; }
   public IPAddress Remote2Address { get; set; }
}
```

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "IpAddressConfig": {
     "HostAddress": "172.17.0.9",
     "Remote1Address": "192.56.0.9",
     "Remote2Address": "192.56.0.10",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution migth be defining your addresses as `string` rather than `System.Net.IPAddress`:

```
public class IpAddressConfig {
    public string HostAddress { get; set; }
    public string Remote1Address { get; set; }
    public string Remote2Address { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can parse your `IPAddress` objects in the calling code as

```
IPAddress hostAddress = IPAddress.Parse(HostAddress);
```

**EDIT**: I have tested the `IPAddressTypeConverter` class that you have provided with the link. Calling the

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(...)
```

line at the top of my `ConfigureServices()` method works for me.